# How can I swap [width] X [height] in a mySQL field?

Tags: mysql

We have a large database with metadata on art. the "format" field has the dimensions of the images  with the height X width

2000 X 800

Back story is interesting, though not germane to the task: this is an old convention used pre-digital age in museums and the art world where descriptions/provenance etc always declared the dimensions of paintings by height first and width second. Most were portrait orientation and i guess it made sense in that physical context to know first how high the "thing" was.

But in today's digital world the standard convention is [width] X [height]

Can anyone formulate an SQL query/statement that read this column

item_format.format

## where this now contains "2000x900" lower case "x" and no spaces

and replace it with

900x2000 in the same field/column?

I can do this with an external livecode script or PHP or something, but seems overkill if there is a way to do it with an SQL statement of some kind...

(obviously:) it requires setting the delimiter to "x" then parsing the string; reassemble in reverse order (item 2 + "x" + item 1) and insert back into the same column/field.. .not sure SQL can actually do that kind of thing if it can... I'm not capable or writing that query.

Comment: how many rows are in this table? Are you adverse to an alter table for a brief period? Are other users active during this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @cFreed's answer, but I would use the builtin function [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). It's a little more clear.

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE yourtable
SET format = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(format, 'x', -1),
  'x',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(format, 'x', 1)
);

-- do a spot check that it did what you intended:
SELECT format FROM yourtable LIMIT 20;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: @ Drew: I appreciate you concerns for a fail safe strategy. cFreed is right. though I'm a sql query novice, I've been managing web servers/services since 1995. The database will be backed up and I plan to do an integrity check on the data of that column just be sure there are no "edge" cases that break the swap. And I will add a "WHERE" clause to constrain to a few records as a test to make sure I am not "foobaring" my data @ CFreed & Bill.. thanks I'll try this soon.. busy today, but probably... I will confirm best answer afterward.  cheers from Kauai.. user is "Brahma"

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work with MySQL (not tested). If you're using another DB, check for possible syntax variations.

```
UPDATE table_name SET format =
CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(format, -POSITION('x', format) - 1),
  'x',
  SUBSTR(format, 0, POSITION('x', format) - 1)
)
```

Comment: backup your data first. This one is going live !

Comment: @Drew Sure it's going live: it's what the OP needs, and I suppose he's aware of what he's doing...

Comment: It doesn't have to go live. If they knew what they were doing, why would they be here.

Comment: @Drew "why would they be here"? Exactly because of what the OP said: " I'm not capable or writing that query". This is not the same as being novice in DB handling. BTW I'm puzzled: how do you think it could be achieved if not live?

Comment: There could be edge conditions on a large subset of rows that a mass update would foobar your data. By having the destination in a staging column for proofing, you could then accept it. Even keep the original in another. So it could go `format`, `proposed`, `formatBackup`. But you guys aren't doing that, and all could be lost. Proceed as you were.

Comment: @Drew I totally agree that it may turn wrong... as well as it's possible in many and many other processes. So in my mind the simpler and common way is to have a backup: it gives the same security level against issues, and it avoids to finally work for completion if no issue happened.